# Audio effect: loop on a keyboard key

Tags: software, midi

Using Mac/Linux/Windows SOFTWARE with an attached MIDI keyboard:

What's the simplest way to, on-demand in live performance, capture a 1-second recording from a microphone and then play it on a loop repeatedly while a particular piano key is pressed?

Comment: Ableton Live would be able to do this. What software do you have at your disposal?

Comment: For the purpose of this OP, assume that we all have access to every software package in existence.   I'm looking for RECIPES -- i.e. follow these precise steps and you've done it!  I thought this would be a nice question to have on SE because it's a very basic functionality that is useful in performance, but inaccessible to clueless newbies like me.  And having multiple RECIPES that achieve this goal in different software environments makes for an enlightening comparison.

Comment: Stack exchange works with real questions and real problems people face, so if you can answer Bart's question that would help us provide answers. Not sure exactly what you mean by recipes...

Comment: "RECIPES -- i.e. follow these precise steps and you've done it!"  A recipe is a series of particular technical steps that lead exactly to accomplishing a stated goal.

Comment: Dr Mayhem and Bart Arondson are right. Rather than having one question covering all software, it would be better to have lots of questions, one each for each significant live performance tool.